# Recreate the Song preview like iTunes store in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, itunes

So i'm almost there, i have the artwork flip when selecting it and it plays the song, the only problem i'm having is when i select a different song in another cell, i can't deselect the current song and flip it back to normal.. i've made a custom cell, which includes a button, and this is the action for the button:

```
-(NSIndexPath*)GetIndexPathFromSender:(id)sender{

if(!sender) { return nil; }

if([sender isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
{
    UITableViewCell *cells = sender;
    return [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cells];
}

return [self GetIndexPathFromSender:((UIView*)[sender superview])];
}

-(IBAction) flipButton: (UIButton *)sender {

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self GetIndexPathFromSender:sender];

SearchTableViewCell *cell2 = (SearchTableViewCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell2.previewButton setSelected:NO];

if (sender.tag == 0) {
    sender.tag = 1;

    [cell2.previewButton setSelected:NO];
    [self.songPlayer pause];

    [UIView transitionWithView:cell2.artworkIMG duration:0.5
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight animations:^{
                           cell2.artworkIMG.image = cell2.artworkIMG.image;
                       } completion:nil];

    [UIView transitionWithView:cell2.previewButton duration:0.5
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight animations:^{
                           //[cell2.previewButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"white.png"]]];
                           [cell2.previewButton setSelected:YES];
                       } completion:nil];
    [self playselectedsong:indexPath];



} else {
    sender.tag = 0;

    [UIView transitionWithView:cell2.artworkIMG duration:0.5
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight animations:^{
                           cell2.artworkIMG.image = cell2.artworkIMG.image;
                       } completion:nil];
    [UIView transitionWithView:cell2.previewButton duration:0.5
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight animations:^{
                           [cell2.previewButton setSelected:NO];
                           //[cell2.previewButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"trans.png"]]];

                       } completion:nil];
    [self.songPlayer pause];

}





}
```

Comment: you need to have reference of last index u played

Comment: How would i go about that?